# F# for scripting: location of script file

Tags: scripting, f#, f#-scripting

In an F# script file (.fsx), how can I determine the location of the .fsx file currently executing?  I'd like to resolve paths relative to it.

I tried `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` but that doesn't work in a "dynamic assembly", apparently.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

extract from F# spec:

_**_SOURCE_DIRECTORY__** - Replaced by a literal verbatim string that specifies the name of the directory that contains the current file, for example, C:\source. The name of the current file is determined by the most recent line directive in the file. If no line directive has been given, the name is determined by that given to the command-line compiler in combination with System.IO.Path.GetFullPath.

_**_SOURCE_FILE__** - Replaced by a literal verbatim string that contains the name of the current file, for example, file.fs

Comment: Even works in F# interactive (no idea *how* - but no matter), thanks!