# F# FAKE Get script directory

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Is there an easy way for me to get the path of the executing .fsx file using FAKE? Powershell and (psake) by nature of its use and MSBUILD provide this functionality but as FAKE/F# a noob it is not immediately apparent how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__` or 
`__SOURCE_FILE__`.

It should work like in every other F# script file see [F# for scripting: location of script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860991/f-for-scripting-location-of-script-file).

Comment: You could also try FullName "."