# C# for scripting (csx) location of script file

Tags: c#, roslyn, csx

In F# it's rather easy with predefined identifier `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4861029/2583080

However this identifier does not work in C# scripting (csx files or C# Interactive).

> > __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
>
> (1,1): error CS0103: The name '__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__' does not exist in the current context

Getting current directory in more traditional way will not work either.

1. `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

   Returns: `C:\Users\$USER_NAME$\`
2. `new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;`

   Returns: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\ManagedLanguages\VBCSharp\InteractiveComponents\`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C# you can take advantage of [caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) attributes (available since C# 5 / VS2012). Just declare a method like this:

```
string GetCurrentFileName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string fileName = null)
{
    return fileName;
}
```

And call it without specifying the optional parameter:

```
string scriptPath = GetCurrentFileName(); // /path/to/your/script.csx
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I tried defining this function in the .csx file as well as in an assembly which I referenced from the .csx and both versions return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

In csx, you are can add `ExecutionContext` as a parameter and access `FunctionDirectory` from it like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ExecutionContext executionContext, ILogger log) {
    var dir = executionContext.FunctionDirectory;

    log.LogInformation($"Directory: {dir}");
}
```

`ExecutionContext.FunctionDirectory` will return the directory the contains the function's `function.json` file. It doesn't include the trailing .

At this time [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#executioncontext) seems to be the best documentation for `ExecutionContext`.

---

*I am trying to find the answer to this question myself, and this was my previous answer.*

In csx, the following helper method will return the directory ["of the source file that contains the caller"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-5.0).

```
using System.IO;

...

public static string CallerDirectory([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string fileName = null)
{
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
}
```

To call it, don't specify the fileName parameter.

```
var dir = CallerDirectory();
```